# Could not generate raft notaries node info with network bootstrapper tool

Tags: corda

I tried to use the network bootstrapper tool to generate the node info files, for participant nodes, node info can be generated successfully, but for notary nodes which are RAFT ones, below error are shown in notary's node-info-gen.log:

```
2018-08-28 09:58:03,982 main WARN Unable to instantiate org.fusesource.jansi.WindowsAnsiOutputStream
2018-08-28 09:58:03,982 main WARN Unable to instantiate org.fusesource.jansi.WindowsAnsiOutputStream

   ______               __
  / ____/     _________/ /___ _
 / /     __  / ___/ __  / __ `/         You know, I was a banker
/ /___  /_/ / /  / /_/ / /_/ /          once ... but I lost interest. 
\____/     /_/   \__,_/\__,_/

--- Corda Open Source 3.2-corda (5ae8325) -----------------------------------------------


Logs can be found in                    : C:\Project\Blockchain\bootstrapper\stage\notary1_node\logs
Database connection url is              : jdbc:h2:tcp://xx.xx.xx.xx:62490/node
[1;31mE 09:58:08+0800 [main] internal.Node.run - Exception during node startup {}
[m java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to find in the key store the identity of the distributed notary the node is part of
    at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode.obtainIdentity(AbstractNode.kt:778) ~[corda-node-3.2-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode.updateNodeInfo(AbstractNode.kt:306) ~[corda-node-3.2-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode.access$updateNodeInfo(AbstractNode.kt:105) ~[corda-node-3.2-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode$generateAndSaveNodeInfo$2.invoke(AbstractNode.kt:183) ~[corda-node-3.2-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode$generateAndSaveNodeInfo$2.invoke(AbstractNode.kt:105) ~[corda-node-3.2-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode$initialiseDatabasePersistence$2.invoke(AbstractNode.kt:685) ~[corda-node-3.2-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode$initialiseDatabasePersistence$2.invoke(AbstractNode.kt:105) ~[corda-node-3.2-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.CordaPersistence.inTopLevelTransaction(CordaPersistence.kt:152) ~[corda-node-api-3.2-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.CordaPersistence.transaction(CordaPersistence.kt:138) ~[corda-node-api-3.2-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.CordaPersistence.transaction(CordaPersistence.kt:124) ~[corda-node-api-3.2-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.CordaPersistence.transaction(CordaPersistence.kt:131) ~[corda-node-api-3.2-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode.initialiseDatabasePersistence(AbstractNode.kt:684) ~[corda-node-3.2-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.internal.Node.initialiseDatabasePersistence(Node.kt:345) ~[corda-node-3.2-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode.generateAndSaveNodeInfo(AbstractNode.kt:179) ~[corda-node-3.2-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.internal.Node.generateAndSaveNodeInfo(Node.kt:353) ~[corda-node-3.2-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.internal.NodeStartup.startNode(NodeStartup.kt:142) ~[corda-node-3.2-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.internal.NodeStartup.run(NodeStartup.kt:115) [corda-node-3.2-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.Corda.main(Corda.kt:13) [corda-node-3.2-corda.jar:?]
```

And below is the node.conf for notary node 1:

```
myLegalName="O=Notary1, L=Zurich, C=CH"
notary {
    custom=false
    raft {
        clusterAddresses=[]
        nodeAddress="xx.xx.xx.01:10001"
    }
    validating=false
}
p2pAddress="xx.xx.xx.01:10002"
rpcUsers=[]
```

And below is the node.conf for notary node 2:

```
myLegalName="O=Notary2, L=Zurich, C=CH"
notary {
    custom=false
    raft {
        clusterAddresses=[
            "xx.xx.xx.01:10001"
        ]
        nodeAddress="xx.xx.xx.02:10001"
    }
    validating=false
}
p2pAddress="xx.xx.xx.02:10002"
rpcUsers=[]
```

And below is the node.conf for notary node 3:

```
myLegalName="O=Notary3, L=Zurich, C=CH"
notary {
    custom=false
    raft {
        clusterAddresses=[
            "xx.xx.xx.01:10001"
        ]
        nodeAddress="xx.xx.xx.03:10001"
    }
    validating=false
}
p2pAddress="xx.xx.xx.03:10002"
rpcUsers=[]
```

Answer (score 0):

We don't support that feature yet, see [JIRA ticket](https://r3-cev.atlassian.net/browse/CORDA-1951).